# Problema Runge Kutta orden 4

Tags: python

que tal? Estoy programando en python una estructura de Runge Kutta de orden 4 que tiene que respetar esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es, ¿hay alguna forma para tomar todos los kji en cálculo de wi+1 e vi+1 sin llamar uno por uno todos los kji?

Mi codigo fue el siguiente:

```
def f(t,w,ki):
fi=-(ki*w)+math.sin(4*t)
return fi

def k11(h,v):
    k=h*v
    return k

def k12(h,t,w,ki):
    fi=f(t,w,ki)
    k=h*fi
    return k

def k21(h,v,k12):
    k=hi*(v+(k12/2))
    return k

def k22(hi,t,w,ki,k11):
    fi=f(t+(0.5*hi),w+(0.5*k11),ki)
    k=hi*fi
    return k

def k31(hi,v,k22):
    k=hi*(v+(0.5*k22))
    return k
def k32(hi,t,w,ki,k21):
    fi=f(t+(0.5*hi),w+(0.5*k21),ki)
    k=hi*fi
    return k
def k41(hi,v,k32):
    k=hi*(v+k32)
    return k
def k42(hi,t,w,ki,k31):
    fi=f(t+hi,w+k31,ki)
    k=hi*fi
    return k
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega datos de entrada y resultados de salida, de modo de poder comprobar que la solución ofrecida esté correcta.